# ACF checkboxes, do not allow multiple selections

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to use ACF checkboxes, but currently you can check off multiple boxes and I dont see an option to not allow multiple selections. Is there a way do force users to only allow 1 checkbox to be checked?

Answer (score 2):

Use the radio field. Checkboxes are designed to allow multiple selections whereas radio boxes are designed to only allow one choice.

Answer (score 1):

hey you could do this by using a little bit of js/jquery something like this should work

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('.checkbox-class').on('click', function(){ 
        if($('.checkbox-class:checked').length >= 2) {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

so it's also possible to define an amount of checkboxes allowed to be checked.